# Node set up/method of recreating this type of displacement

Tags: modeling, node-editor, displacement, distort

Does anyone have any idea how this type of mesh displacement is achieved. I'm assuming the artist has begun with a seemingly normal human model and has applied loads of crazy displacements onto it to create this type of warped, mutant look

but does anyone have any ideas of a particular node set up? or is this somethings that more easily achieved in sculpt?

I'm basically looking to create and control as much distortion to meshes as possible and recreate this sort of skin folding idea

help??

specifically the [image]

Comment: A simple displacement modifier could do kind of things, but probably this needs a little more work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmdVA.jpg and of course it depends on base model.

Comment: "funny"... haven't tried that before https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjQ81.gif

Comment: Thanks so much, this has really helped :)